# How to use htmlspecialchars() correctly?

Tags: php, web

Would I just do something like

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['example'])));?
```

Comment: You need to mention what you're trying to do before anyone can tell you what  you would want to do...

Comment: Just read `http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php` You'll have your answer

Answer (score 2):

htmlspecialchars function is used to encode characters those have special meaning in HTML language. Thus, there is no direct connection between this function and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`htmlspecialchars` coverts HTML characters like `<` and `>` to "entities", `&lt;` and `&gt;`, respectively.

It's used so that HTML tags aren't parsed by the browser, they are just displayed literally on the page.

Whether you want to use this or not before inserting into a database depends on what you want to do with the data.